# Is it the Na+ or the Cl- that gives table salt its taste?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, halides, taste

What gives it that salty taste? I'm wondering if it's the $\ce{Na+}$ or the $\ce{Cl-}$. I know that [$\ce{KCl}$ also tastes salty, and other salts have different flavours](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19631/do-all-salts-taste-salty),  but where does the saltiness in $\ce{NaCl}$ come from? I mean, it makes sense that it's the $\ce{Cl-}$ ion, but it could also be that $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{Na+}$ have similar flavours.

Comment: Mostly Cl-. Taste some baking soda, it is not quite salty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The salt receptors are sodium ionic channels, i.e. peptides which are selectively permeable for Na ions [[1](http://www.hhmi.org/news/sodium-detecting-taste-receptors-identified)].
Ionic current causes receptor activation and neural responce.

Anion plays minor role here, imposing upon salty taste. The result may appear acidic, bitter and even sweet.
For example, I believe that sulphates are overally bitter.
Carbonates or alkali probably just burn the receptors and may have random taste.

Comment: Sodium cyanide is reported to taste like common salt, I am not inclined to find out if the story is true or not,